# How can I remotely create an event in someone else's Google accounts after they have logged in my website?

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

What I'm trying to do is, establishing a link between a user 1 and my website and their Google Calendar account.

As soon as another user 2 accept's user 1's request it should automatically sync user 2's birthday to user 1's Google Calendar and user 1's birthday to user 2's Calendar.

How can I make this possible with Google Calendar API ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to remember is that Google Calendar data is private user data. In order to access private user data like a users Google Calendar account you need the users permission. To do that we use Oauth2.

Both user one and user two will need to authencate your application and grant your application consent to write to their google calendar.

- When you create your application, you register it using the Google API Console. Google then provides information you'll need later, such as a client ID and a client secret.
  Activate the Google Calendar API in the Google API Console. (If the API isn't listed in the API Console, then skip this step.)
- When your application needs access to user data, it asks Google for a particular scope of access.
- Google displays a consent screen to the user, asking them to authorize your application to request some of their data.
- If the user approves, then Google gives your application a short-lived access token.
- Your application requests user data, attaching the access token to the request.
- If Google determines that your request and the token are valid, it returns the requested data.

read more [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/auth)